# Download google drive folder's file via wget

Tags: linux, wget, google-drive

I want to download google drive folders file via wget how it is possible?

I have folder **version** in google drive and in that version folder all version apk file of my mobile app.

Folder tree like this

```
Version : -> mobileapp1.apk
          -> mobileapp2.apk
          -> mobileapp3.apk
```

And I want to download by passing version name. Is it possible with google drive and wget? I have already make folder **Public on the web - Anyone on the Internet**

Answer (score 1):

You need to get each fileID from google drive and generate links like described here [in google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/1vJ8aqNSzaw)

A FTP Server would make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Good day! 
I do not know which distribution you use, but some of them can connect to Google Drive by the operating system itself. For example, Fedora. It is enough to set up network accounts...
After that, access to the Disk will be through the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

To download with `wget`:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -r 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FIELDID' -O FILENAME
```

where `FILENAME` is the output file name you want, like `mobileapp1.apk`
and `FIELDID` is the ID in your file link.

Example

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/xxx/view
```

xxx will be your file ID.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question in another question: [Downloading large folder from google drive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580432/downloading-large-folder-from-google-drive)

I wrote a Python code using the PyDrive library, that can recursively retrieve the sub-folders and files inside a parent folder. Using the ids of the files, I then generated a bash script using wget.

**Step 1**
I have used the PyDrive library. To use this library, you have to complete the instructions described in this [link](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html#authentication).

Step 2
Now, create a python script or notebook in the same working directory, where you have saved the “client_secrets.json” file. I have attached the notebook below.

https://gist.github.com/immuntasir/73b8e8eef7e6c9066aaf2432bebf7db0

**Step 3**
Using scp, copy the “script.sh” to the remote server.
`scp ~/path/script.sh username@ip:path`

**Step 4**
Login to the remove server, navigate to the path. Then make the script executable using the following command.
`chmod 777 script.sh`
Run the script and voila!
`./script.sh`

I also wrote a tutorial, which can be found here: https://medium.com/@immuntasir/recursively-download-all-the-contents-of-a-google-drive-folder-using-python-wget-and-a-bash-script-d8f2c6b105d5

Hope this helps!

Comment: This requires the user of the script to enable google drive API and authenticate, for what otherwise doesn't require any authentication through the browser.