# Downloading large folder from Google Drive

Tags: shell-script, curl, wget, download, google-drive

I want to write a script to download [this folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5bVaQ5pgJ-raDhkUjRMZEFiS0E?usp=sharing) from Google Drive. The script is aimed for non-expert UNIX users so I don't want to use more than curl or wget. 
I've seen solutions with the fileid, but I cannot manage to get the fileid in my case.

Is there anyone that managed to download folders from Google Drive?

Here are the solutions I tried:

- [How to download a folder from google drive using terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136371/how-to-download-a-folder-from-google-drive-using-terminal)
- [Downloading Shared Files on Google Drive Using Curl](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f0f2d122e05bf5f971611258c22c110f)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest up-to-date solution (2021) I found to download large folders from google drive is gdrive:

http://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive

```bsh
gdrive download --recursive --skip <file_id>
```

where `<file_id>` is the id you get from the folder URL. No need to configure anything, it will already ask you for your credentials and such.

The `--skip` flag is useful for large folders, since the download might time out at some point. You then rerun the command and `--skip` will make it act like an `rsync`.

As of this date, `--skip` is a relatively new flag and is available if you install `gdrive` through Go. If your system `gdrive` doesn't have it, try the same without `--skip`. Then, if you really need it, install it using `go get` as described in the github readme page.

Comment: As of March 2022, the binary that is downloadable from github includes the `--skip` flag

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Python code using the PyDrive library, that can recursively retrieve the sub-folders and files inside a parent folder. Using the ids of the files, I then generated a bash script using wget.

**Step 1**
I have used the PyDrive library. To use this library, you have to complete the instructions described in this [link](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html#authentication).

Step 2
Now, create a python script or notebook in the same working directory, where you have saved the “client_secrets.json” file. I have attached the notebook below.

https://gist.github.com/immuntasir/73b8e8eef7e6c9066aaf2432bebf7db0

**Step 3**
Using scp, copy the “script.sh” to the remote server.
`scp ~/path/script.sh username@ip:path`

**Step 4**
Login to the remove server, navigate to the path. Then make the script executable using the following command.
`chmod 777 script.sh`
Run the script and voila!
`./script.sh`

I also wrote a tutorial, which can be found here: https://medium.com/@immuntasir/recursively-download-all-the-contents-of-a-google-drive-folder-using-python-wget-and-a-bash-script-d8f2c6b105d5

Hope this helps!

Comment: This requires the user of the script to enable google drive API and authenticate, for what otherwise doesn't require any authentication through the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Your fileId is on the url adress of your folder, you can simply run

```
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O FILENAME
```

Comment: You did not read my question no?